# Actionbar replaced with Toolbar showing Logo at Top left with App name ... workaround

Tags: android, android-actionbar

As mentioned in the title I am expecting my Android App to show Actionbar / Toolbar with Logo at its left, followed by App name in the form of Title.
I had to perform some workaround in each activity so as to omit the text designed as a label in Android manifest.
Below I am providing code snippets for quick reference -

activity_main.xml ... Toolbar tag -

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/myLogo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/myTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="My App name"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Android manifest - Application tag -

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="My App name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Styles.xml - Handling no actionbar

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

onCreate of AppCompatActivity -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle("");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_horizontal);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
        titleText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
```

Now, from onCreate, if I remove or comment - `setTitle("");`
then ... output toolbar starts with label picking from Android manifest, followed by Logo, then TextView text indicating App name.

If I blank the label from Android manifest then, App launcher generated in the mobile is with a blank name.

By putting line - `setTitle("");` I see it as workaround. Is there any elegant way, where I can omit the label from Android manifest appearing into the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this, so you can do ur custom title

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

and then manually `setText` to your textView inside toolbar

if you insist to get the title from manifest, you can do this

```
ActivityInfo activityInfo = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(
                getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
String title = activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                .toString();
```

Comment: Facing null pointer exception at - getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); This is largely because I am setting No action bar via manifest.

Comment: do this after 'setSupportActionBar(toolbar);'

Comment: Thanks this worked. Also I see approach from you is more elegant.

Comment: if this works and help, please accept the answer and give upvote, cheers~